# Expandable listview fragment <implementation issue>

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, expandablelistview, android-listfragment

I have two tabs using tabhost. One tab having activity extends ExpandableListActivity. It works fine. Now I wanted to use actionbar for adding a layout. But it crash because of tabhost. so I thought of using actionbar for tab. I wanted to add the expandable list activity into actionbar's tab. but its not adding as a tab.

so I have 2 question here.

1. Can't we use activity in actinbar's tab.
2. If no then is there any implementation in fragment for expandable list view.
3. Or Can I have tabhost and actionbar both together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got alternative of this problem. solution of problem 2.
As fragment don't have implementation like ExpandableListFragment so better we can declare expandlistview in layout file so no need to extend ExpandableList class. 
Still I am looking for answer of question 1.